# How to Add an icon to an ubuntu app

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk

I have developed an App for ubuntu in python using quickly.
I packaged it and is working perfectly but i could not find how to add an icon to my App currently its like a blank icon.

I have used Glade and gtk.

Comment: I have written a tutorial on how to do this: http://ptomato.github.com/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/desktop-file.html

Comment: @ptomato your link is broken

Comment: It should be https://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/desktop-file.html - GitHub broke the username.github.com domains several years ago, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to install a "named icon". To do this, your installation script will copy the file to a specific location which is dependent up on the user's system, but typically `<datadir>/icons/hicolor/<size>/app/<app-name.png|svg>` where `datadir` is something like `/usr/local/share`. The minimum suggested icon sizes are typically a scalable icon with SVG format and a PNG icon that is 48x48 pixels.

Once you've copied the icons to the right place, you can update GTK's cache using the gtk-`update-icon-cache` command.

When you've installed a "named icon", your application can refer to it by name:

```
window = Gtk.Window
window.set_icon_name("myapp")
```

Now, one other thing you'll need to do, is install a "destop entry" file. These tell Ubuntu (or GNOME or KDE or Xfce) about your application so that it can be launched and also what it's icon is. You create the file according to the [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and copy it to `<datadir>/share/applicaions/` with a `.desktop` file extension. You can see examples in `/usr/share/applications/` from applications installed on your system. You could also use [Desktop Entry Editor](https://github.com/Quixotix/desktop-entry-editor) to create the `.desktop` file. In the desktop file, the icon would be set to your "named icon" too.

So all in all, to install a named icon and a desktop entry, you're looking at something like:

```
/usr/local/share/applications/myapp.desktop
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/myapp.svg
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/myapp.png
```

Comment: /usr/local/share is not correct for most situations; according to Debian rules that is reserved for administrators. Should be /usr/share/...

Comment: An admin would typically be installing a source tarball and thus the prefix would be /usr/share. If you've got the resources to maintain binary distributions (.deb, .rpm, etc.) then you would follow the distributions rules such as /usr

Comment: Can one add the icon to one's home? I am trying to add an icon to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/` but I can't

Comment: @WolterHellmund: you can't, how? `~/.local/share/icons` works fine in Debian/Ubuntu, that's where I install icons used by my custom scripts and manually installed games. Remember the directory structure: `hicolor/WIDTHxHEIGHT/apps/APPNAME.png`

Comment: I want to set an icon for a mimetype, namely `text/todo`, so I put an icon in `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/text-todo.svg`. After I run the `update-icon-caches` command, `text/todo` files I have on my desktop don't show the icon. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to run `gtk-update-icon-cache -f -t /path/to/theme/` im pretty sure running `gtk-update-icon-cache` by itself does nothing. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-update-icon-cache.html @SeveroRaz

Comment: Output: `gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid`