# PyGobject Application Icon

Tags: python, pygobject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Add an icon to an ubuntu app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979412/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-ubuntu-app)

I am trying to create a base application code for the PyGObject app. I am not sure how to change the application icon.

I have this code.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I have checked some of the sample codes and didn't found a way to do that. Any pointers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979412/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-ubuntu-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using a file relative to the script:

```
win.set_icon_from_file("logo.png")
```

For using a theme icon:

```
win.set_icon_name("logo.png")
```

PyGObject still doesn't have a decent API documentation (the last time I checked), for now you can use C API and old PyGtk documentation and "guess and try" what you need: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/ & http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/